# how to return IEnumerable List values to View page in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Getting data in a list format using IEnumerable,How to return to View page from controller.

model.Name = UserPermissions.Name; is this correct format?

List containing name,Id,Amount,Currency for each plan.

model.Name = UserPermissions.Name;  getting error here.from list pass all data to view dynamically in DIV.How to pass data and display in view.help me guys

```
   public ActionResult Plans(Plan model)
{
    var planServicenew = new StripePlanService(apiKey);
            IEnumerable<StripePlan> responsenew = planServicenew.List();
            foreach (var UserPermissions in responsenew)
            {
                model.Name = UserPermissions.Name;
            }
    return View(model);
}
```

## view page

```
@model IEnumerable<ABACUS.Models.Plan>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <div class="plan">
            <h3 class="plan-title">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</h3>
            <p class="plan-price">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Currency)@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount) <span class="plan-unit">per month</span></p>
            <ul class="plan-features">
                <li class="plan-feature">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Trial)-days <span class="plan-feature-name">Trial</span></li>

            </ul>
            <a href="#" class="plan-button">Choose Plan</a>
        </div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have "Plan" model and you want to pass the list of Plans to your view,

try below way to resolve your issue -

```
var planServicenew = new StripePlanService(apiKey);
        IEnumerable<StripePlan> responsenew = planServicenew.List();

        var plans = (from r in responsenew
                    select new Plan
                    {
                        Name = r.Name,
                        Currency = r.Currency,
                        Amount = r.Amount,
                        Trial = r.Trial
                    }).ToList() as List<Plan>;
         return View(plans);
```